# Deploying a chrome extension hosted on store

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I want to deploy a Chrome extension hosted on Chrome store.

According to:

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions.html

I need to include a CRX file, so how do I get it from the Chrome store?
I can't pack it using my own *.PEM key since it won't install and the key differs from the one generated on the Chrome store.

So, please, how do I deploy it?

Comment: Why vote down? I plan to deploy my own extension, not to steal or anything. I just want to understand how does it work. I've searched and couldn't find a straight answer.

Comment: My question was just voted down as well, but at least I got some explaination: it is not a programming issue. In that case I wish I knew why chrome-web-store tag exists, this tag doesn't concern programming by definition at all.

Comment: it has something to do with code, I guess. Nonetheless, I would be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The whole content of the crx is landing in the chrome directory, more specifically:

> c:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
>   Data\Default\Extensions\

All installed extensions are listed here by their ID's.

Comment: yes, but in order to deploy an extension you must provide a crx. Are you suggesting to deploy an unpacked extension? it wont work since Chrome hosts an index for each installed extension... it doesn't scan this path.